# How do I assign 2 different variable to the return values from a function that return 2 values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry for the very messy title. What I have is a function that returns 2 different values:

```
def func(name):

return value1, value2
```

Now I would like to assign these 2 values to variables in one line. This is what I have tried:

```
x,y = func(name)[0] , [1]
```

The x variable is assigned correctly, but the y variable is assigned just assigned as [1].
If it relevant: The [0] is an array and the [1] is a DataFrame form a .csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. It's even simpler than you think, you can extract without reference to indices:

```
def func(name):
    # do something
    return value1, value2

x, y = func(var)
```

`func` returns a tuple (note parentheses are not required). You can then unpack via sequence unpacking. I would advise you choose variable names that are informative.